# How to build a transparent ImageButton in Android?

Tags: android

I want to build a transparent ImageButton, I put these buttons in a SurfaceView. But when I put the code in XML, Eclipse returns an error. I don't know how to solve, any help will be appreciated.

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/previous"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/media_skip_backward"
android:background="@drawable/transparent">
</ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/media_skip_backward" >
</ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is in res/values create colors.xml file and add transparent color code in it. something like

```
<resources>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="Black">#000000</color>
    <color name="Trans_Black">#80000000</color>
    <color name="Trans_Black_Darker">#BB000000</color>    
</resources>
```

Now change your path to `android:background="@color/transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

You just try this types of code in your xml file

```
 <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/previous"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:src="@drawable/media_skip_backward" >
```